# How to install pybluez on win10?

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth

I want to install python Bluetooth module from pip on my Windows 10's Python3.8(32 bits). But it comes up with these errors which I cannot understand. I tried pybluez, pybluez-win10, win10 SDK and even replace the socket file with the one from GitHub. Does anyone can help me with that? Here are the error messages.

[error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyDHR.png)

[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRqaR.png)

Comment: The first screenshot has a linking error - you need to find the Irprops.lib file. A quick search for that shows that it's been removed from the Windows SDK (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/06/04/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-18908-available-now/) so you probably need to find a different bluetooth module which has been updated to use the now-12-months-old SDK

Comment: But where I can get the new bluetooth module for python? The win10 version is the newest one I can find.

Comment: You might just have to edit the setup.py file in the source yourself - https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/setup.py#L34 is where you can make that change

Comment: Or install a pre-built version https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pybluez. Btw, if you read https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez you'll note that contributors are wanted because the code isn't under active development. Which is another way of saying that it's up to you :-)